# Getting multiple key values from Ionic2 storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using Ionic2 storage, I have done the following in a custom provider, I can confirm that the key-value pairs are set and I can retrieve them individually:

```
this.storage.set('one', 1);
this.storage.set('two', 2);
this.storage.set('three', 3);
```

The problem is I have a function in one of my pages that needs to access all three of these values for an HTTP request, so I can get one of them like this:

```
this.storage.get('one').then((value) => {
    // Preform http request sending value in POST data
});
```

But how do I get multiple key values all at once? Do I need to nest these calls, or is there a simpler way to access multiple keys in one call, so that I can do something like:

```
this.storage.get(['one', 'two', 'three']).then((values) => {
    console.log(values.one); // I dunno, something like this
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do it as shown below.

```
this.storage.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
    console.log("value", value);//store these values as you wish
    console.log("key", key);
    console.log("Index" index);
})
```

[**From Api Doc.**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts#L212)

```
 /**
   * Iterate through each key,value pair.
   * @param iteratorCallback a callback of the form (value, key, iterationNumber)
   * @return Promise that resolves when the iteration has finished.
   */

  forEach(iteratorCallback: (value: any, key: string, iterationNumber: Number) => any): Promise<null> {
    return this._dbPromise.then(db => db.iterate(iteratorCallback));
  }
```

Comment: I've tried that, but is there a way to specify which keys I want, or do I need to loop through all of them? Thanks very much Sampath.

Comment: Yes, You have to loop through all the keys and if you need to pick specific key then you have to use `if` `else` statements.

Comment: Okay - and how can I know when the entire looping and my assignments are done, because after I get the values only then do I want to make my HTTP request. Thanks again!

Comment: I suppose I just chain a `.then()` block after?

Comment: Yes, of course.You can use `.then()`.Hence those are `promises` no. Please see this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/#forEach

Answer (score 11):

I used Promise.all for this purpose

```
Promise.all([this.storage.get("email"), this.storage.get("username")]).then(values => {

      console.log("email", values[0]);
      console.log("username", values[1]);

      // every other thing can happen here e.g call a method

});
```

Comment: I use this too, it's preferred over other listed methods.